# How to share weights using tf.layers.conv2d

Tags: tensorflow, share, conv-neural-network

I have built an autoencoder using tf.layers.conv2d layers and would like to train it in phases. That is to train the outer layers first then the middle layers and then the inner. I understand this is possible using tf.nn.conv2d because the weights are declared using tf.get_variable but I would think this should also be possible using tf.layers.conv2d.

If I enter a new variable scope different from the original graph to change the inputs to the convolutional layers (i.e. skip the inner layers during phase 1) I am not able to reuse the weights. If I do not enter a new variable scope I am not able to freeze the weights that I dont want to train in this phase.

Basically I am trying to use the training method from Aurélien Géron here https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/15_autoencoders.ipynb

Except I would like to use a cnn instead of dense layers. How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

No need to create the variables by hand. This works just as well:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 512, 512, 3), name='inputs_1')
inputs_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 512, 512, 3), name='inputs_2')

with tf.variable_scope('conv'):
    out_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs_1, 32, [3, 3], name='conv_1')

with tf.variable_scope('conv', reuse=True):
    out_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs_2, 32, [3, 3], name='conv_1')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(tf.trainable_variables())
```

If you give `tf.layers.conv2d` the same name, it will use the same weights (assuming `reuse=True`, otherwise there will be a `ValueError`).

**In Tesorflow 2.0:** `tf.layers` were replaced by keras layers where the variables are reused by using the same layer object:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(512, 512, 3)), 
])

@tf.function 
def f1(x):
    return model(x)

@tf.function 
def f2(x):
    return model(x)
```

Both `f1` and `f2` will use the layer with the same variables

Comment: Yeah I agree with you that it works this way as well, and it's hope I'd opt to do it if I was writing the code. I just meant that if you're relatively new to tensorflow, creating all of the weights by hand can give a clearer idea of what exactly is going on - it takes away some of the black box elements.

Comment: Instead of repeating `tf.variable_scope(...)` with the same name, you can just call `scope.reuse_variables()`.

Comment: Can you please update this answer to Tensorflow 2.0? Thanks!

Comment: @becko Tensorflow 2.0 does not have `tf.layers` but I added a similar example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting it up a little bit differently. Instead of using tf.layers.conv2d, I would explicitly make the weights using calls to tf.get_variable() and then use these weights with calls to tf.nn.conv2d(). This way, you don't blackbox the variable creation, and can reference them easily. It's also a good way to learn exactly what's going on in your network, since you wrote the shapes for every set of weights by hand!

Sample (untested) code:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, 512, 512, 3), name='inputs')
weights = tf.get_variable(name='weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 16], dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope("convs"):
    hidden_layer_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input=inputs, filter=weights, stride=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
with tf.variable_scope("convs", reuse=True):
    hidden_layer_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(input=hidden_layer_1, filter=weights,stride=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME"
```

This creates convolutional weights and applies it twice to your input. I haven't tested this code, so there may be bugs, but it's about how it should look. References here for [variable sharing](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables) and here for [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d).

Hopefully that helps! I would be more thorough, but I have no idea what your code looks like.

Comment: Can you please update this answer to Tensorflow 2.0? Thanks!